# Deduce that $\frac{F_1}{N_1}>\frac{F_2}{N_2}$

Tags: inequality

Given that $W>0$, $F_1=F_2$, $N_1 + W=N_2$,  $F_1\cos70+F_2=N_1\cos30$ and $N_2=F_1\sin70 + N_1\sin30$ deduce that $\frac{F_1}{N_1}>\frac{F_2}{N_2}$. I combined the third and fourth equations and tried rearranging the terms after using equations one and two but didn't get anywhere with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$${F_1 \over N_1}={F_1 \over (N_2-W)}>{F_2 \over (N_2)}$$
OR:
$${N_1 \over F_1}={(N_2-W) \over F_1}<{N_2\over F_2}$$